# I couldn't find my .js file on firebug

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, firebug

Firebug made me crazy. I want to debug my javascript codes but I couldn't find my js file.

It show the error why is line of my search .js file but when I search I couldn't find.

I search PersonManagement.js on firebug
[image: I search PersonManagement.js on firebug]

But when I search on script section on I couldn't find, I need to review via debug this file, I mean I need to find PersonManagement.js via firebug.

[image: But when I search on script section on I couldn't find, I need to review via debug this file, I mean I need to find PersonManagement.js via firebug.]

Could you help me?

Comment: The Firebug screenshot is showing a syntax error. Unfortunately the related source link is cut off. Could it be that this error is in your PersonManagement.js?

Comment: yes definately this error in my PersonManagement.js and I solved yesterday. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If there is a syntax error within a JavaScript source, the source is not listed within the *Script* panel, though the syntax error is logged to the *Console* panel (assumed you have the option *Show JavaScript Errors* enabled).

This is also [briefly explained within the Firebug FAQ](https://getfirebug.com/faq#Why_does_the_Script_panel_claim_there.27s_no_JavaScript_on_the_page_when_there_obviously_is_code) and the [*Script* panel description](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Script_Location_Menu).

In your case you got the syntax error 'missing name after . operator'. Just remove the `.` between `$` and `(` and your problem should be solved.